# How to keep scripts persistent during admin-ajax process when saving widget?

Tags: ajax, widgets

Is there a hook to keep scripts that are included with widgets, persistent during the `admin-ajax.php` process?

I use jQuery `show()` to open an element within a widget and the element should remain closed until clicked, and that works as expected. However when the widget is saved and WP is doing ajax at admin-ajax.php, the the function fails and opens without any interaction. If the page is reloaded, the function returns to normal.

The function is running from a file `myscript.js` and loaded in `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.

```
 $(".handle").click(function(){
    $(".element").show("slow");
 });

<span class="button handle">View Details</span>
<div class="element">this is detail</div>
```

I suspect the widget is then at admin-ajax.php and the JS is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

After deep meditation and a meeting with dally the llama (maybe it was an alpaca, I was quite high), I've defined a solution.

Use the `widget-updated` var to reload the JS function on widget save.

```
$(document).on('widget-updated', function(event, widget) {
    doAccordion();
});
```